# django not adding element to list

Tags: django, list, session

here's what I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label=‘New Task’)
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label =‘priority’,
               min_value=1,max_value=5)

Create your views here.
def index(request):

    if "tasks" not in request.session:
        request.session['tasks'] = []

    return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {    
                "tasks": request.session['tasks']
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == “POST”:
        task = request.POST.get(‘task’)
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data[“task”]

            request.session['tasks'] += [task]
            # or we can try doing it this way
            # request.session['tasks'] += task            
    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tasks:index"))            
        else:
            return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
                "form": form
            })

return render(request, "tasks/add.html",{
    "form": NewTaskForm()
})
```

and then in index.html we have:

```
{% extends ‘tasks/layout.html’ %}

{%  block body %}
    <h1>Tasks</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for task in tasks %}
        <li>{{task}}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No tasks</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">Add a new task</a>
{% endblock %}
```

HERE’S THE PROBLEM:

if we use request.session[‘tasks’] += [task] where task = ‘abc’

we get in the html abc

but if we use: request.session[‘tasks’] += ‘abc’
we get in the html :

a

b

c

Comment: Don't think I understand what the issue is - in one case you're adding a list in the other you're adding a string - are you running into errors somewhere?

Comment: in the first case we get ['abc'] and in the second case we get ['a','b','c']

Comment: Yes - that is normal python behavior - what are you trying to do that you cannot accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is but maybe this explanation will help:

```
# adding two lists:
l1 = [1, 2]
l1 += ['abc']
print(l1) # prints [1, 2, 'abc']

# adding a string to a list:    
l2 = [5, 6]
l2 += 'abc'
print(l2) # prints [5, 6, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```